# SQL Query Questions for a text (Nested NOT EXISTS)

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, exists

I have been struggling with this for a while now so maybe someone can shed some insight.

We have a practice query that comes from a TVShow database that for this problem has 4 tables.

This is the query: **Sponsors that sponsor all tv shows by ABC**

What I have tried so far is this but it doesn't seem to be working:

`SELECT DISTINCT RSPONSOR.SPONSOR_NAME
FROM RSPONSOR
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM RTVSHOW
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM RSPONSORBY
    WHERE RSPONSOR.SPONSOR_NAME = RSPONSORBY.SPONSOR_NAME
    AND RSPONSORBY.SHOW_NUM = RTVSHOW.SHOW_NUM
    AND RTVSHOW.NETWORK_ID = 'ABC'
  )
);`

Would love any help! Thanks in advance.

Here are the tables for reference

**--RTVSHOW--**

```
SHOW_NUM    NUMBER

SHOW_NAME   VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)

START_MONTH NUMBER

START_YEAR  NUMBER

END_MONTH   NUMBER

END_YEAR    NUMBER

NETWORK_ID  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)

DISTR_NAME  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
```

**--RSPONSOR--**

```
SPONSOR_NAME

PARENT_NAME
```

**--RSPONSORBY--**

```
SHOW_NUM

SPONSOR_NAME
```

**--RNETWORK--**

```
NETWORK_ID

NETWORK_HQ

PARENT_NAME
```

Comment: Consider outer joins, and good luck with your homework :)

Comment: Also consider excluding sponsors that don't sponsor at least one show. Currently you select all ABC shows for which no sponsors exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
select rSponsor.sponsor_name, rSponsor.parent_name
from rSponsor
join rSponsorBy
    on rSponsor.sponsor_name = rSponsorBy.sponsor_name
join rTVShow
    on rSponsorBy.show_num = rTVShow.show_num
join rNetwork
    on rTVShow.network_id = rNetwork.network_id
where rNetwork.network_id = 'ABC'
group by rSponsor.sponsor_name, rSponsor.parent_name
having count(distinct rTVShow.show_num) = --ABC shows sponsored by this sponsor
(
    select count(distinct rTVShow.show_num) --ABC shows
    from rTVShow
    join rNetwork
        on rTVShow.network_id = rNetwork.network_id
    where
        rNetwork.network_id = 'ABC'
);
```